# Java Spring Boot Rest API 400 Bad Request

Tags: spring-boot, sockets, tcp, http-status-code-400, rest

I am trying to make a async Rest API with Spring Boot.

The Rest API receives http requests that have a json body with one value "zahl", then it extracts that value, opens a socket and sends a tcp request with that number to a loadbalacer, that divides the Requests on different servers.
They all make the same and calculate wheter the given number is a prime or not.
If it is, it returns a String for example: "(89) is prime: (true)" or "(10) is prime: false".
The result goes back over the loadbalancer to the Rest API and finally to the client.

That's how it should works.

But for most requests I get Bad Request 400. Sometimes it works fine.

[400 Bad Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34FUe.jpg)

Therefore I tried to do the calculation directly instead of opening a socket and it works perfectly.

So the problem is the Socket right?

Here is my Code:

```
package javaRestApi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MyRestController extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRestController.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyRestController.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private AsyncService service;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyRestController.class);
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/request/json", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String jsonRequest(@RequestBody RequestModel body) throws IOException, Exception {
        log.info("new Request");
        CompletableFuture<String> result = service.isPrime(body.getZahl());
        log.info("Result: " + result.get());
        return result.get();
    }
}
```

```
package javaRestApi;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class RequestModel {
    private String zahl;
    
    public void setZahl(String zahl) {
        this.zahl=zahl;
    }
    
    public String getZahl() {
        return zahl;
    }
}
```

```
package javaRestApi;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {
    
    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

And finally the class where I create the Socket...

```
package javaRestApi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;

import java.net.Socket;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AsyncService {

    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<String> isPrime(String zahl) throws IOException, Exception {
        
        //direct calcualtion
        int z = Integer.parseInt(zahl); 
        if(prime(z))
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("" + z + " is prime");
        else 
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("" + z + " is no prime");
        
        //with Tcp Connection
        //return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("3"/*tcpClient(zahl)*/);
    }
    
    //local prime calculation
    private static boolean prime(int zahl) {
        for(int i = 2; i<zahl; i++) {
              if(zahl % i == 0) { 
                  return false;
              }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    // TCP connection to load balancer
    private static String tcpClient(String zahl) throws IOException, Exception {
        java.net.Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 12345);
        senden(socket, zahl);
        return lesen(socket);
    }

    // send the value to Socket
    static void senden(java.net.Socket socket, String zahl) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter prwr = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        prwr.print(zahl);
        prwr.flush();
    }

    // get the result from the socket
    static String lesen(java.net.Socket socket) throws IOException {
        int Buflength = 40;
        BufferedReader bufR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        char[] buf = new char[Buflength];
        int anzZeichen = bufR.read(buf, 0, Buflength);
        String retString = new String(buf, 0, anzZeichen);
        return retString;
    }
}
```

And here the Stacktrace.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-06-26 20:22:36.106  INFO 71152 --- [           main] javaRestApi.MyRestController             : Starting MyRestController on DESKTOP-FVOQ69M with PID 71152 (C:\Users\Fill07\Desktop\javaRestApi\target\classes started by Fill07 in C:\Users\Fill07\Desktop\javaRestApi)
2020-06-26 20:22:36.110  INFO 71152 --- [           main] javaRestApi.MyRestController             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/C:/Users/Fill07/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-06-26 20:22:37.870  INFO 71152 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-26 20:22:37.884  INFO 71152 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-26 20:22:37.884  INFO 71152 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-06-26 20:22:38.213  INFO 71152 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-06-26 20:22:38.225  INFO 71152 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-26 20:22:38.225  INFO 71152 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2041 ms
2020-06-26 20:22:38.356  INFO 71152 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-06-26 20:22:38.358  INFO 71152 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'asyncExecutor'
2020-06-26 20:22:38.845  INFO 71152 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-26 20:22:38.860  INFO 71152 --- [           main] javaRestApi.MyRestController             : Started MyRestController in 3.385 seconds (JVM running for 3.941)
2020-06-26 20:22:40.830  INFO 71152 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-06-26 20:22:40.830  INFO 71152 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-06-26 20:22:40.841  INFO 71152 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 11 ms
2020-06-26 20:22:40.977  INFO 71152 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] javaRestApi.MyRestController             : new Request
2020-06-26 20:22:41.013  INFO 71152 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] javaRestApi.MyRestController             : Result: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: cl
```

I don't understand what is wrong, i mean sometimes it works.

How can I fix it?

Is it maybe a problem with Tomcat?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you provide the error stack trace too for the java program?

Comment: Yes, but there is not much

Comment: ok i solved it, there was an error in the server to calculate the prime numbers

Comment: I have the same issue. Mine is a very simple API. It gives 200 and if I suddenly send the request, it gives 400 for the same one. I have only one instance running